# Prove $\sin(x) \le x$ for all $x\ge0$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, mean-value-theorem

EDIT: This has to be done without calculus methods. I.e. noting $h'\ge 0$ won't do. I have used the mean value theorem, however this has been deemed permissible.

Prove $\sin(x) \le x$ for all $x\ge0$.
Consider the function $h(x)=x-\sin(x)$. Then, $h(0)=0-\sin(0)=0$
Consider an interval $[0,y]$ for $y>0$. $h(x)$ is continuous on $[0,y]$ and differentiable on $(0,y)$, thus the conditions of the mean value theorem are satisfied. Therefore,
$$\exists c\in(0,y): h'(c)=\frac{h(y)-h(0)}{y-0}=\frac{h(y)}{y} $$
Note that $h'(x)=1-\cos(x)$. This means $0 \le h'(x) \le 2$, paticualrly $h'(c) \ge 0$.
Then, $$\frac{h(y)}{y}\ge0$$ We know $y>0$ so $$h(y) \ge0 \implies y-\sin(y)\ge0 \implies y\ge\sin(y) \text{ for } y\ge0 $$ as required. Is this proof valid?

Comment: It looks OK,  .You may have a shortcut,  using just the fact that $h'\ge 0$, so $h$ is monotone in the whole real line

Comment: @dmtri Should have specified, no calculus techniques allowed.

Comment: But you are using mean value theorem...

Comment: This is true, however this is permissible in my analysis course.

Comment: OK,  then you are right

Comment: If another approach would interest you, a famous triangle-sector comparison handles the case $x\le\pi/2$, which is sufficient because $\sin x\le1$.

Comment: Who is this instructor who says "no calculus" but mean-value theorem ok?  The mean-value theorem is the most basic part of the calculus. How about no calculus but complex analysis ok?  Define exponential function by its power series $\exp(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}z^n$.  Define $\sin t$ as the imaginary part of $\exp(it)$.  Inequality follows easily.  "Look ma, no hands (I mean no calculus)."
This is how Rudin (Real and Complex Analysis) dispenses with the trig functions in a couple of pages.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Well, we have proven the MVT in lectures, however other elements of calculus have not been rigourously proven yet.

Comment: I see.  But I rather think it would be better to extract your argument and do it this way: "First I will prove a lemma stating that any differentiable function  $h:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ with a nonnegative derivative is nondecreasing.  [Do so].  Then claim that the inequality follows from the lemma by setting $h(x)=x-\sin x$."  That way you are "doing calculus" but not using any unproved statements for this course.  The phrase "without calculus methods"  really doesn't mean anything here.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson I could do it that way, but why would I if my current proof is correct?

Comment: Your current proof is correct.  You will receive a full grade for it.  If you want to rise above the level of a calculus course you might start to think about things this way.  Your argument works in much greater generality than just this example $h(x)=x -\sin x$.  State and prove the more general result and then deduce the particular from it.  "Correct" is not the goal.  When you publish a mathematical result, only the first step is "correct" and then a long time polishing, generalizing, simplifying, etc.  Get in the habit early.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson fair enough, thanks for the advice.